# Apache starting automatically with the system

Tags: 22.04, apache2, security, xampp

Using 22.04 on a laptop. I have XAMPP installed, but when I try to start XAMPP through Terminal, it says

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 8.2.0-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
```

I was puzzled because there is no reason Apache should be running on its own. So I shutdown the system and then started it again, and tried

```
sudo systemctl status apache2.service
```

I got this and more saying Apache is running

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor prese>
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-12-26 21:18:54 IST; 50s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 1136 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SU>
   Main PID: 1292 (apache2)
      Tasks: 55 (limit: 27942)
     Memory: 7.8M
        CPU: 41ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─1292 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─1293 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─1294 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Is it possible to find out which / what is starting Apache and using it? I couldn't find anything under startup applications other than Nvidia X Server Settings and SSH Key Agent.

Is it a security issue? Should I be worried? What should I do? Thanks.

**Edit 1** :

I should add that this XAMPP is been in use on this laptop for around 6 months now. I used sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start 2 days before too without any issues. Suddenly today, XAMPP won't start and giving this issue. That is why I am confused.

**Edit 2** :

I checked the logs and found this

[image]

**Edit 3** :

```
$ apt-cache policy apache2
apache2:
  Installed: 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7
  Candidate: 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.52-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how a Debian system works and Ubuntu is derived from Debian.

Once you installed a service, the service will be started unless that very specific service is setup differently (which is really rare).

You can first stop it before trying to start XAMPP:

```
systemctl stop apache2
```

or disable the auto-restart so on your next reboot it won't be running until you start it:

```
systemctl disable apache2
```

At the same time, MySQL should also auto-start and thus on a reboot your XAMPP should be up and running on its own by default. There should be no need to start XAMPP at a later time.

Comment: Thanks. I should add that this XAMPP is been in use on this `laptop` for around 6 months now. I used `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` 2 days before too without any issues. Suddenly today, XAMPP won't start and giving this issue. That is why I am confused.

Comment: Did you install Apache directly or as an dependency from the Ubuntu sources? The shown systemd Service Units looks very much like it.

Comment: @user227495 That comment is something you need to add in your question. Otherwise, we'd have no idea! And a comment here won't be visible to the next person reading your question.

Comment: Comment added as edit to the original post. @noisefloor I installed XAMPP like 6 months ago on this machine based on some tutorial. I didn't install Apache directly as far as I know. The funny thing is there was no error like this 48 hours ago. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy apache2` to our question.

Comment: @noisefloor added, please check.

Answer (score 2):

The **Edit 3** shows that you have Apache installed from the Ubuntu sources, too. So you have the manually installed version via XAMPP and the version installed from Ubuntu's sources. As the version installed from the sources is by default started automatically via a systemd Service Unit while the system starts, you cannot start another version of Apache manually at a later point.

You could remove the Apache installed from the sources

```shell
sudo apt remove apache2
```

or stop the Apache from the sources and prevent that it is loaded as a dependency by another unit

```shell
sudo systemctl stop apache2.service
sudo systemctl disable apache2.service
sudo systemctl mask apache2.service
```

However, prior to doing this you may want to find out why Apache was installed from Ubuntu's sources and if another package / program you are using maybe depends on a running Apache server.

*Addition 1*: To verify when the apache package was installed you can check the file **/var/log/apt/history.log**. This file holds information when which package was installed.

Comment: Thanks, exactly my problem. I did nothing that I understand about installing another version of Apache. This if happened, was in the last 2 days and I did nothing major during that period. Not sure what / which is responsible for the action.

Comment: @user227495: see addition 1 in my answer on how to determine when the Apache package was installed.